# Lint failed when using gradle build android app

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, lint

I created an app with android studio, but every time I try to use command `gradle build` to build the application, it says "lint failed". When I checked the debug info of gradle build, it said:

```
21:10:26.215 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Daemon,5,main]] finished, busy: 1.263 secs, idle: 0.034 secs
21:10:26.219 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
21:10:26.221 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
21:10:26.222 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
21:10:26.222 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
21:10:26.223 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':MyApp:lint'.
21:10:26.224 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > class org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
21:10:26.225 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
21:10:26.226 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
21:10:26.228 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':MyApp:lint'.
21:10:26.229 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
21:10:26.229 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
21:10:26.230 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
21:10:26.231 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
21:10:26.231 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
21:10:26.232 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
21:10:26.233 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
21:10:26.233 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
21:10:26.234 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
21:10:26.235 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:289)
21:10:26.235 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
21:10:26.236 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
21:10:26.237 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
21:10:26.237 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
21:10:26.237 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
21:10:26.238 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
21:10:26.238 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
21:10:26.239 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
21:10:26.239 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
```

I have searched a lot but could not find a solution for it.
Anyone can help about it? Thank in advance.

Comment: It turned out that there is a bug about lint of gradle before. I am not sure it was resolved yet. but you can use the build parameter to forbid lint with:`gradle -x lint build`

Answer (score 7):

I fixed the same issue by adding `lintOptions` in build.gradle :

```
android {

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

**IntelliJ hinted**  :
Fix the issues identified by lint, or add the following to your build script to proceed with errors:

Comment: I added these in the my build.gradle, but the issues still happened.

Comment: Is it possible to do this from the top level script like in the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420391/how-to-disable-lint-abortonerror-in-android-gradle-plugin-from-top-level-of-mult?