# app:processDebugResources - IllegalArgumentException (no error message)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When build Gradle i get this error message:

```
Error:00:29:02.408 [ERROR]   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
00:29:02.408 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 00:29:02.408 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
00:29:02.408 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
00:29:02.408 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
00:29:02.408 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (no error message)
00:29:02.408 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
00:29:02.408 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
00:29:02.408 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
00:29:02.408 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
00:29:02.409 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
00:29:02.409 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
00:29:02.409 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
00:29:02.409 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
00:29:02.409 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
00:29:02.409 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
00:29:02.409 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
00:29:02.409 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
00:29:02.409 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
00:29:02.409 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
00:29:02.409 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
00:29:02.409 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
00:29:02.409 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
00:29:02.409 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
00:29:02.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
00:29:02.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
00:29:02.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
00:29:02.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
00:29:02.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
00:29:02.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
00:29:02.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
00:29:02.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
00:29:02.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
00:29:02.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
00:29:02.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
00:29:02.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
00:29:02.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
00:29:02.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:196)
00:29:02.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
00:29:02.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
00:29:02.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
00:29:02.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
00:29:02.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
00:29:02.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
00:29:02.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
00:29:02.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
00:29:02.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:50)
00:29:02.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
00:29:02.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
00:29:02.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
00:29:02.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
00:29:02.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
00:29:02.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
00:29:02.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
00:29:02.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:75)
00:29:02.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
00:29:02.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
00:29:02.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
00:29:02.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
00:29:02.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
00:29:02.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
00:29:02.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
00:29:02.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
00:29:02.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
00:29:02.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
00:29:02.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
00:29:02.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
00:29:02.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
00:29:02.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
00:29:02.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
00:29:02.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
00:29:02.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
00:29:02.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
00:29:02.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
00:29:02.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
00:29:02.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
00:29:02.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
00:29:02.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
00:29:02.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
00:29:02.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
00:29:02.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
00:29:02.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
00:29:02.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
00:29:02.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
00:29:02.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
00:29:02.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
00:29:02.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
00:29:02.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
00:29:02.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
00:29:02.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:108)
00:29:02.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.symbols.Symbol.<init>(Symbol.java:114)
00:29:02.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.symbols.SymbolIo.read(SymbolIo.java:79)
00:29:02.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:896)
00:29:02.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:194)
00:29:02.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:82)
00:29:02.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
00:29:02.414 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:163)
00:29:02.414 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
00:29:02.414 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
00:29:02.414 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
00:29:02.414 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
00:29:02.414 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 78 more
00:29:02.414 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
```

I tried rebuild, clean, i hve installed SDK tools.

Here is my Gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.bolt.skola"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}


}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Please do this and [edit] your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674091/how-to-add-stacktrace-or-debug-option-when-building-android-studio-project

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/23690365/2308683

Comment: @cricket_007 nothing:(

Comment: Did you upgrade your Gradle to `3.3+`? And upgrade Android Studio to 2.3?

Comment: Same issue observed after upgrading gradle version 3.3 and Android studio 2.3.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you don't have spaces in your activity name in xml. That was the reason in my case.

Comment: While this wasn't the cause of my error, I went through my layouts and found that I was missing a drawable since I had copied the code from another project.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem resolved.
In my case, Even in my case exception was being thrown while processing resources. So I realised problem is with resources I am providing.
So I went through all resource xml file under my project. Here I found one xml file which want not used/referred at all had one bug. Bug was just typo, Extra space in android xml tag values. I removed them and problem solved.

android:paddingLeft=" 2dip"
android:id="@+id/ itemList"

Only question now is, How previous gradle plugin (2.14.1-2.2.3) was ignoring this unused xml file and At least latest gradle plugin (2.3-3.3) build process should have thrown more meaningful exception.